# window procedures for dialog box controls

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I've created a dialog box with buttons in it using Visual Studio's resource editor, and I want the buttons to display different icons under different circumstances.

I gather that in order to set an icon for a button, I need to send a `BM_SETIMAGE` message to a window procedure for that button.

I'm not clear on what handling such a message would involve, but I haven't gotten to the point of figuring that out, because I don't see how to associate a window procedure to a button in the first place.  I'm used to associating a window to its window procedure by passing a pointer to the procedure into the function that initializes the window, but that doesn't seem to apply here since the buttons are initialized automatically when I initialize the dialog box.

I thought there might be a way to specify window procedures for controls in the resource editor, but if there is, I'm missing it.

Comment: A button is a window.  How do you send a message to a window?  `SendMessage` (or `PostMessage`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I knew that much, but when a message is sent to a window, doesn't it need to be handled by a window procedure that belongs to that window in order to do anything?

Comment: _Every_ window has a window procedure.  In the case of a standard button, it is something internal to windows (or handled by MFC).

Comment: When a dialog is created from resource, it already has default window procedures assigned to its child controls.  You assign your own window procedure (via `RegisterClass/Ex()`, `SetWindowLongPtr()`, or `SetWindowSubclass()`) only when you need to customize message processing, which is not the case here since you are working with standard buttons, so just get a button's `HWND` via `GetDlgItem()` and send it the `BM_SETIMAGE` message, the OS will handle the message for you.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ah, so the point is that in the case of a predefined control, one doesn't have to supply a window procedure because one already exists as part of the internal works of the button, and already handles all messages specific to the control in the way one would expect them to be handled. That clears up my confusion about what it would mean to handle the message too.

Comment: @Remy Got it. The wrinkle I'm running into now is getting the dialog box's handle for use in GetDlgItem(). I need the dialog box to be modal, so it seems none of the possible functions for initializing it have a handle as a return value. As a first approximation, I tried GetWindowFunction(), commenting out the one other child window the dialog box's parent had to remove ambiguity and calling the function with the parent window's handle and GW_CHILD from the WM_INITDIALOG case of the dialog box's window procedure, but for some reason it returned NULL.

Comment: @Alex When you handle `WM_INITDIALOG` you already have the window handle of the dialog because it is the first parameter of `DialogProc`. Call `GetDlgItem` with this handle and the control ID of the button to get the handle of the button.

Comment: @zett42 Oh, haha, it's obvious now that you point it out. I was trying to get it to work from outside the window procedure (which I eventually realized probably doesn't make sense because the dialog box only exists for the line where DialogBox() is called as far as the caller is concerned...right?) for so long that I guess I was overthinking it.

Comment: When using `DialogBox()` you are right. You could create a modeless dialog though (using `CreateDialog()` for instance), in which case you could do this from outside the window procedure.